# Manga about a guy and a female alien fighting other aliens that are based on types of gems

Tags: story-identification, aliens, manga, martial-arts

I remember reading this manga like 2 to 4 years ago.

It was like the princess of the aliens (who is a diamond) somehow destroyed their planet. I don’t really remember how, but they come to Earth and are looking for these special stones that have powers in them.

Later you find out that the former princess is now going to the main character’s school and I think people thought she was really poor. But somehow, the main character, the princess and one of the teachers (who was also an alien) end up fighting in a lab or observatory, and the main character gets one of those special rocks into his hand. He now has fire powers and then the princess convinces him to help her find the other stones, if I remember correctly.

The main character's mom is like a martial arts instructor or something.

Comment: What did these character look like? Did any of them look especially unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a decent chance you're looking for *[Holy Crystal Albatross](https://kaminomi.fandom.com/wiki/Seikessh%C5%8D_Albatross)* (originally *Seikesshō Albatross* (聖結晶アルバトロス)).

[image: Cover image of the third issue of *Holy Crystal Albatross*]

> One day, junior high-schooler Yuuki helps a girl from another class, a weird girl known throughout the school as the "Trash Girl." Because of this selfless act, Yuuki's life undergoes a dramatic change. It is then revealed the "trash girl" is Asakura. And through a series of mishaps, Asakura is actually an alien called "monobail" who is searching for holy crystals to save the world from evil "monobailes". After agreeing with Asakura to help her search for these crystals, Yuuki encounters many monobailes (Whose elements are based on the periodic table of elements).

Found through a search for *manga alien princess "high school" stones mother "martial arts"*, which led me to [the TV Tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/SeikesshouAlbatross), which led me to search for the series name. Fair warning, the manga got canceled after five issues, leaving the plotlines unresolved.

Comment: That’s definitely it thanks so much